# Gitlab running job issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I commit my changes on gitlab server, I have an error on job running :

[git error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITa8J.png)

Anynone can help please ?

Gitlab version : GitLab Community Edition 8.17.4
Gitlab runner version : 1.11.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade your Gitlab. I believe there are some incompat issues with Gitlab Runner and Gitlab.

Comment: What is the type of runner you have? Docker, ssh, shell?

Comment: I have a shell runner

Comment: Ah, what version of git are you running on that runner?

Comment: I upgraded my gitlab and my runner so I use Gitlab 10.4.2 and gitlab-runner 10.0.0

Comment: Yes but what version of git is installed on the machine where your runner is installed. It seems to be an issue with the machine and its git installment.

Comment: I have git 2.7.4 installed on the same machine

Comment: Try cleaning your build directory to force a new clone.

Comment: I cleaned my builds directory. It seems that cloning repo is not working because the .git file does'nt appear

Comment: Permissions issue?

Comment: May be ... How I can check permissions during runner process?

Comment: Log on to machine and change user to `gitlab-runner`

Comment: I logged as gitlab-runner and I tried to run runner locally but I have same error